# importing library modules using a frequent imports approach

Tags: f#

Suppose there is a set of frequent imports that I would like not to have to repeat in every module. Is there a way to specify "frequent imports" that could be called instead. For example something like:

```
module frequentImports =
    open System
    open System.IO
    ...
```

Then instead of having to retype all the imports individually, the frequentImports module could be called instead. Obviously, the above approach doesn't work for me which is why the question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to define something like a group of `open` statements and then just refer to the group. Generally, you just need to have all your `open` statements once per file.

The fact that you have too many of them that you want to repeat all the time might suggest that your code organisation is not optimal - I would think that if you have code structured by putting logically related things into a single file, then each file would need different imports.

One thing you could do - though I don't think it's all that nice - is that you could define a module with module and type aliases for the things you commonly need.

Say, if I wanted to avoid opening `Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection` and `System.Collections.Generic`, I could define a module with aliases for the things I need:

```
module MyThings = 
  type Dictionary<'k,'v> = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<'k, 'v>
  type FSharpType = Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType
  type FSharpValue = Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection.FSharpValue
```

Using `open MyThings` now gives me access to the three types (and the same would work for modules too). That said, this does not automatically import all definitions and I think it's probably not worth doing this - but it's an option.